# jvm crash.. not enough free memory? (1.6)

Tags: java, jvm

I got this from crash log.. looks like free memory is super low (1020k) that time, is it caused by too few memory?

I have 10g RAM and my GC settings are: 
`-Xmx5g -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=700`.

Can someone please give me some hints? Thanks!

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f220198ce10, pid=26470, tid=1154627904
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (19.1-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J  com.twitter.typeahead.server.topic.TopicTypeAheadController$2.onSuccess(Lcom/twitter/typeahead/common/MetastoreResult;)V
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

Current thread (0x00007f21f2ce0800):  JavaThread "New I/O client worker #1-18" [_thread_in_Java, id=26628, stack(0x0000000044c23000,0x0000000044d24000)]


siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=2 (SEGV_ACCERR), si_addr=0x00007f2200e4616a

Registers:
RAX=0x00000006bae61950, RBX=0x00000007fafe2be0, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x00000006bbe2d580
RSP=0x0000000044d22180, RBP=0x00000006bae61950, RSI=0x00000006bae61950, RDI=0x00007f220198ccf0
R8 =0x00000000d77c5ab0, R9 =0x00000006bbd0a190, R10=0x00000000035df16a, R11=0x00007f21fd867000
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000044d22180, R14=0x0000000000000001, R15=0x00007f21f2ce0800
RIP=0x00007f220198ce10, EFL=0x0000000000010207, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000006
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00000006bae61950

[error occurred during error reporting (printing registers, top of stack, instructions near pc), id 0xb]

Stack: [0x0000000044c23000,0x0000000044d24000],  sp=0x0000000044d22180,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
```

Comment: IMHO, the free_space is the stack space that is still available on the stack. Are you using native code ?

Comment: I assume you're using a 64-bit JVM?

Comment: the free space is only 1020k, not sure if that's enough. and yes, I'm native code.. only related lib is finagle

Comment: can you add the jvm version? I don't think it is related to native code, as the crash causing thread was the nio worker.

Comment: Have you tried a different version?

Comment: See the answer I provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455381/java-jit-compiler-causing-outofmemoryerror

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are running out of memory. This is an error for a segfault in the JVM.

Try reading these stackoverflow posts. They should point you in the right direction:

[Java VM: reproducable SIGSEGV on both 1.6.0_17 and 1.6.0_18, how to report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299250/java-vm-reproducable-sigsegv-on-both-1-6-0-17-and-1-6-0-18-how-to-report)

[how to debug SIGSEGV in jvm GCTaskThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645870/how-to-debug-sigsegv-in-jvm-gctaskthread)

Well unless the JVM has a bug where it is hitting a segfault or a buffer overrun without first crashing on not enough stack memory remaining, try setting -Xss (the per thread stack size) to a higher value.