# C2 Compiler saturating CPU at startup

Tags: java, performance, jvm

I have a java servlet application on Java 7 that is normally very healthy in terms of system resource consumption. Normally CPU usage on the server is below 50%. However in the few minutes following startup it behaves much differently, to the point that the CPU can become pegged at 100% for several minutes if its trying to serve a lot of traffic during that period. The result is slow response times, network timeouts, and even long garbage collection pauses sometimes.

To diagnose the issue, I took a series of thread dumps while the server was starting up and I ran top -H at the same time. By matching each java thread to a pid, I can consistently see the `C2 CompilerThread` using by far the most CPU. I have done research about what this thread does and I understand that it is a Java compiler optimizing code based on runtime statistics. But from all the reading I've done, I can't tell the best approach to making the situation better. The only options I can glean are:

1. Switch from C2 to TieredCompiler (but will this result in better performance in the first few minutes after startup?)
2. Turn on -XX:+PrintCompilation to see what is being optimized (but what do I do with this information? Can I force it to be optimized before the server is accepting traffic somehow?)

What is the best approach to take and are there other options to try and alleviate CPU usage after startup?

Comment: Once you find out where all the code compiling is going, look at ways of reducing it.  This might mean removing a library which is particularly expensive.  IMHO it's not normal to have some much code that the C2 has to spend long periods of time compiling.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but I'm not sure what I'm looking for. Just the most frequently compiled methods? Or methods labeled "made zombie" or "made not entrant"? There's just nothing obvious jumping out at me.

Comment: Which packages compile the most methods I. E. Which jar dies this come from?

Comment: Maybe the C2 runs out of memory and has to throw away compiled methods and recompile them again and again? Just a guess based on seeing a related discussion somewhere. Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3482393/581205) could help?

Answer (score 1):

There are several paid-for JVM technology available to alleviate your problem, using ahead-of-time compilation.

However, if you want to stick to the standard JVMs, one trick people use is after startup you send a few dummy requests so that the JVM is warmed up before your actual operation starts. That way you can decide when you want to pay for the JVM warm-up cost before serving your customers.

You can also ***force the JVM to compile all code*** by -Xcomp command line options for hotspot, but *we don't recommend it* as it will slow down the start up of your application by compiling seldomly used code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem after invoking `instrumentation.retransformClasses(clazz);` for the first time. `instrumentation` is java.lang.instrument which is about java agent.

here is what retransformClasses doing from JDK source code.

```
    /**
     * Retransform the supplied set of classes.
     *
     * <P>
     * This function facilitates the instrumentation
     * of already loaded classes.
     * When classes are initially loaded or when they are
     * {@linkplain #redefineClasses redefined},
     * the initial class file bytes can be transformed with the
     * {@link java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer ClassFileTransformer}.
     * This function reruns the transformation process
     * (whether or not a transformation has previously occurred).
     * This retransformation follows these steps:
     *  <ul>
     *    <li>starting from the initial class file bytes
     *    </li>
     *    <li>for each transformer that was added with <code>canRetransform</code>
     *      false, the bytes returned by
     *      {@link java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer#transform transform}
     *      during the last class load or redefine are
     *      reused as the output of the transformation; note that this is
     *      equivalent to reapplying the previous transformation, unaltered;
     *      except that
     *      {@link java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer#transform transform}
     *      is not called
     *    </li>
     *    <li>for each transformer that was added with <code>canRetransform</code>
     *      true, the
     *      {@link java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer#transform transform}
     *      method is called in these transformers
     *    </li>
     *    <li>the transformed class file bytes are installed as the new
     *      definition of the class
     *    </li>
     *  </ul>
     * <P>
     *
     * The order of transformation is described in the
     * {@link java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer#transform transform} method.
     * This same order is used in the automatic reapplication of retransformation
     * incapable transforms.
     * <P>
     *
     * The initial class file bytes represent the bytes passed to
     * {@link java.lang.ClassLoader#defineClass ClassLoader.defineClass} or
     * {@link #redefineClasses redefineClasses}
     * (before any transformations
     *  were applied), however they might not exactly match them.
     *  The constant pool might not have the same layout or contents.
     *  The constant pool may have more or fewer entries.
     *  Constant pool entries may be in a different order; however,
     *  constant pool indices in the bytecodes of methods will correspond.
     *  Some attributes may not be present.
     *  Where order is not meaningful, for example the order of methods,
     *  order might not be preserved.
     *
     * <P>
     * This method operates on
     * a set in order to allow interdependent changes to more than one class at the same time
     * (a retransformation of class A can require a retransformation of class B).
     *
     * <P>
     * If a retransformed method has active stack frames, those active frames continue to
     * run the bytecodes of the original method.
     * The retransformed method will be used on new invokes.
     *
     * <P>
     * This method does not cause any initialization except that which would occur
     * under the customary JVM semantics. In other words, redefining a class
     * does not cause its initializers to be run. The values of static variables
     * will remain as they were prior to the call.
     *
     * <P>
     * Instances of the retransformed class are not affected.
     *
     * <P>
     * The retransformation may change method bodies, the constant pool and attributes.
     * The retransformation must not add, remove or rename fields or methods, change the
     * signatures of methods, or change inheritance.  These restrictions maybe be
     * lifted in future versions.  The class file bytes are not checked, verified and installed
     * until after the transformations have been applied, if the resultant bytes are in
     * error this method will throw an exception.
     *
     * <P>
     * If this method throws an exception, no classes have been retransformed.
     * <P>
     * This method is intended for use in instrumentation, as described in the
     * {@linkplain Instrumentation class specification}.
     *
     * @param classes array of classes to retransform;
     *                a zero-length array is allowed, in this case, this method does nothing
     * @throws java.lang.instrument.UnmodifiableClassException if a specified class cannot be modified
     * ({@link #isModifiableClass} would return <code>false</code>)
     * @throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException if the current configuration of the JVM does not allow
     * retransformation ({@link #isRetransformClassesSupported} is false) or the retransformation attempted
     * to make unsupported changes
     * @throws java.lang.ClassFormatError if the data did not contain a valid class
     * @throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError if the name in the class file is not equal to the name of the class
     * @throws java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError if the class file version numbers are not supported
     * @throws java.lang.ClassCircularityError if the new classes contain a circularity
     * @throws java.lang.LinkageError if a linkage error occurs
     * @throws java.lang.NullPointerException if the supplied classes  array or any of its components
     *                                        is <code>null</code>.
     *
     * @see #isRetransformClassesSupported
     * @see #addTransformer
     * @see java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer
     * @since 1.6
     */
    void
    retransformClasses(Class<?>... classes) throws UnmodifiableClassException;
```